# What's the best approach to attach events in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, element, document

I was messing with one of my friends codes and I see he likes to use most of the events like this:

```
$(document).on(event,selector,function());
```

And I like to use this form:

```
$(elementParent).on(event,selector,function());
```

The difference is obvious, he likes to attach events to document and I like to do it to their parents. The question is, which way is more efficient, more logical or the best?

Comment: Totally depends on the situation. The more specific you are, the less events need to propagate up the chain to take affect (slightly better performance too).  The less specific you are the more compatibility you get with dynamically added/removed html nodes.

Answer (score 4):

***It depends.***

Either way, you're using event delegation, which means that in theory, a directly-attached handler can get in your way. Which is fine if either A) There are no directly-attached handlers, or B) You *want* them to get in the way/jump the queue.

In terms of efficiency, I very much doubt there's any significant difference for most events. Maybe with an event that fires a **lot**, like `mousemove`, you might want to pay attention to see if you were getting lag and, if so, move the handler closer to the actual element. Also, since jQuery attaches a single handler per event per element and then does its own dispatching from there, having a **lot** of handlers on `document` *might*, theoretically, start getting a bit slower. But the usual advice is to worry about that if/when you see an actual problem. With modern JavaScript engines, my guess (and it is a guess) is that you'd need a ***lot*** of handlers attached to `document` before you started noticing an issue.

Handling them at the document level means you have a broader surface to add elements to (the entire document) and have them covered by the handler. Sometimes that's good. Other times it doesn't make sense. For example: If you have a handler for events related to a specific table, it doesn't make sense to handle those at the document level, because...they're specific to the table.

My rule for this, which is subjective, is simple: Handle the event at the outermost level it relates to. Sometimes that's `document`, but most times it's at a container a bit closer to what I'm working with — the outermost element of a widget, or a table, or a content section, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited the post. And thanks too for this incredible answer, I think I'll keep using a common parent for different sections.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be as specific as you are... which will limit the number of selectors that need to be evaluated.

Take the case of an delegated click event handler attached to the document object. This will require any click event to evaluate the selector passed to find out whether to trigger the handler. But if you had targeted a more specific element then only those click events which happens inside the attached handler will invoke the selector evaluation.